# How to create a button using onTouch?

Tags: android, button, touch-event, oncreate

I want to write a program which creates a button, whenever I'm touching the screen, the button should be created on the place where  the screen was touched.

I wrote a program which creates circles, whenever and where the screen is touched, can anybody explain me how to make buttons instead of circles?

Thx.

**Main Activity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class SingleTouchActivity extends Activity  {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new SingleTouchEventView(this, null));
  }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.single_touch, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```

**Touch Activity**

```
import java.util.ArrayList; //not all imports are necessary
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class SingleTouchEventView extends RelativeLayout {
  private Paint paint = new Paint();
  List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();



  public SingleTouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);}



@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:  // a pointer was moved
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        Point p = new Point();
        p.x = (int)event.getX();
        p.y = (int)event.getY();
        points.add(p);

        Button button = new Button(getContext());

        int buttonHeight = 50;
        int buttonWidth = 50;

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        params.leftMargin = p.x;
        params.topMargin = p.y;

        addView(button, params);


        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //DO SOMETHING! {RUN SOME FUNCTION ... DO CHECKS... ETC}
            } 
        });

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
      break;
    }
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;  

}

        // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make your class extends a `ViewGroup` like `RelativeLayout` and `FrameLayout` in your case.

Then, on the touch event, create a `Button` (or a `ImageView` and `setOnClickListener()`), adjust the position of the button with margins on the view `LayoutParams` and add the button to the layout via `addView()`.

Edit: The button creation will be like this on `onTouchEvent()`:

```
Point p = new Point();
p.x = (int)event.getX();
p.y = (int)event.getY();
Button button = new Button(context);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
params.leftMargin = p.x;
params.topMargin = p.y;
addView(button, params);
```

Also change this to be inside `ACTION_UP` to prevent creating multiple buttons on long pressing.

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you explain the creating of the button a bit more in detail, because I don't know how to do it...:/

Comment: thx for the help, I don't know why but the Button(context) is marked as "context cannot be resolved to a variable", any idea?

Comment: You can call `getContext()` to have a context or save the context from constructor.

Comment: Yep, I noticed it also ! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You can draw a circle because that is a graphic. If you were to make button appear then you would need to add it to XML. I assume you are making a game that requires elements to randomly appear. I suggest if this is the case to use and engine a spawn random circles and when touched do what you need. Hope this helps

Comment: No they should appear where the screen is touched, becuase after you clicked the button, the app opens a little window in which you should be able to insert some information and this input should be reeditable if you click on the button another time...

Comment: Then make the background touchable and set a listener to do something when touched

Comment: So as you can see in my code, whenever the screen gets touched its position gets saved in a x/y value, I am able to draw circles, that works fine, so my problem isn't the touching, it's how to create a button instead of a circle, because as I wrote above, I need to open a window...

Or is it possible to make the circles clickable? 
Or should I compare the coordinates of the location where the screen gets touched and every time, the comparison is true it opens a window..?

Comment: yes you can make the circles clickable and then they will do what you need them to do onClick

Comment: and how, maybe a hint?